# Some users lose their custom claims after page reload

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, active-directory

I am using .NET Core, with Azure Active Directory authentication through my free Azure account. The goal is for the user to log in, my web app to poll the database and figure out what access they have, and add that access into claims. Then, when a page is reloaded, I can use .NET Core's new Policies or order to validate the user.

This seems to work perfectly for my Microsoft account, however, when I try to use an account that I created in my Azure Active Directory, the claims are lost as soon as the user tries to change pages. I've verified via debugging that the claims are added after login, and are there on the initial front-page load, but are lost as soon as the user changes pages or refreshes.

So, in my `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` I have:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    foreach(var accessPolicy in AccessPolicy.GetAllPolicies())
    {
        options.AddPolicy(accessPolicy, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new CanAccessRequirement(accessPolicy)));
    }
});
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CanAccessHandler>();
```

And, in the `Configure` method I have:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    ClientId = ApiLogin.ClientId,
    ClientSecret = ApiLogin.ClientSecret,
    Authority = ApiLogin.Authority,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration["AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
    CallbackPath = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:CallbackPath"],
    GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = false,

    Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
    {
        OnRemoteFailure = OnAuthenticationFailed,
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived
    }
});

private Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
{
    if (!Session.Keys.Contains(Constants.AUTH_TOKEN))
    {
        var email = user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value ?? user.Identity.Name;
        if (email == null || !email.Contains('@')) return;

        // This is the security token needed to talk to the API. 
        // Putting it as a magic value, since it doesn't have anything 
        // to do with the current problem
        string token = "123";

        Session.Set(Constants.AUTH_TOKEN, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(token));

        // Add the claims
        var claims = ApiLogin.LoginUser(token, email) ?? new List<string> { };
        (user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).AddClaims(claims.Select(p => new Claim(p.ToString(), "True")));
    }

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Finally, in my controllers, I have lines like this above my classes, where `AccessPolicy` just holds constant strings.

```
[Authorize(Policy = AccessPolicy.EditInvoicePrivilege)]
```

I cannot figure out why this works for me on my `@hotmail` account but does not work when I try to use my `@[TenantId]` account.

Am I doing something wrong with the claims? And if so, why does it work for one account, and not the other?

Please let me know if you need any more information. Unfortunately, there's a lot of code, so recreating with a minimal amount of code is still a lot of code.

Comment: Maybe this isn't the problem but AzureAd does not return an email address in `ClaimTypes.Email` (`http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress`) but the email address is either in `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name`
or `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn` (WIF claimtypes). Can you debug your find email check?

Comment: @user1336, looks like it comes back in two ways. for the @hotmail, I get it back in `claims/name` and `claims/emailaddress`. `claims/name` is weird though, as it's prefaced by `live.com#`. For the @[TenantId] one, I get it back in `claims/upn` and `claims/name`, where both are just the email address.

Comment: That sounds about right, does this pass your email check and resolves the issue?

Comment: @user1336, the email part is working fine. The reason I store it is because I use that to get the permissions from the database. It's the custom claims I add at the bottom that are disappearing.

Comment: Did you mean that the code adding custom claims was executed and after that page reloading make the custom claims disappearing? If I understand correctly, is the page a special page or any page reloading will cause this issue?

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT, the code that adds the claims is only run after the user logs in. From there, they're redirected to the home page, and when that page's controller is hit, the claims are there. When that page is refreshed (F5) or when they click a link to another page, and the same page or new page's controller is hit, the claims are gone. -- Does that answer the question?

Comment: @David Yes. The code seems to be right. Did you have any code sample which can reproduce this issue?

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT, I don't have something outside of the code that is posted, since the majority of the code not shown is default boilerplate code. If you're trying to avoid the whole setup part with Azure and stuff, DM me and I'll give you the repo.

Comment: @David Actually I am trying to reproduce the issue however failed. I have upload the test code sample to [here](https://github.com/VitorX/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore). You may check whether it is helpful.

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT, Can you take a look at the change I just made? Missed an `if` statement when minimizing the code. Your example sets the claims on every page-load.

Comment: @David There maybe some misunderstanding. The code I provided will only add the custom claims when the token is verified after user enter the correct username/password and redirect from identity data provider. It is same as you use the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` event. The adding custom claims behavior only will fire once. Would you mind sharing how you initialize the `session` object and what's the value of `Constants.AUTH_TOKEN`? So that I can add the test the code to test whether the issue was cause by these code.

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT `app.UseSession()` and `services.AddSession()` is how I get session. `Constants.AUTH_TOKEN` is just a static string. Are you using an account created in Azure AD, or are you using your default Microsoft account when you try it?

Comment: I am testing using the account created in Azure AD. And I am still not able to use the `Session` object in the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived`, here is the code I am trying `if(context.HttpContext.Session.Keys.Contains(""))`.  And where you set the session value for `Constants.AUTH_TOKEN`?